# What is the correct DateTimeFormatter pattern for datetimeoffset column

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, datetimeformatter

What is the correct DateTimeFormatter pattern for querying a SQL Server table by a datetimeoffset column. When I execute the below query, I get results. What is the correct pattern I should use to run the same query from the java app?

```
SELECT *
FROM
       TABLE
WHERE
       CreateTimestamp >= '2020-07-06 06:00:00.0000000 +00:00'
```

Below is the java code snippet I use to convert the date:

```
public String convertToDatabaseColumn(OffsetDateTime offsetDateTime) {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd-HH.mm.ss.SSSSSS Z");
        return offsetDateTime.format(formatter);
    }
```

Below is the snippet that sets the parameter and executes the query

```
Date beginDt; // passed to the method as parameter
Date endDt; // passed to the method as parameter
OffsetDateTime beginDateTime = beginDt.toInstant().atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC);
OffsetDateTime endDateTime = endDt.toInstant().atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC);
params.put(BEG, convertToDatabaseColumn(beginDateTime));
params.put(END, convertToDatabaseColumn(endDateTime));
List<Map<String, Object>> newfuelList = sqlJdbcTemplate.queryForList(sqlForNewFuel, params);
```

I get the following exception

```
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

Comment: `yyyy-MM-dd-HH.mm.ss.SSSSSS Z` If you check that again, you'll notice you have a `-` between `d` and `H`, not a `T` or `' '`.

Comment: What is the datatype of `CreateTimestamp` in the database? Aren’t you using the built-in `timestamp with time zone` datatype? If not why not? I certainly think you should. (Don’t know exactly what it’s called in SQL Server, but there certainly is an equivalent.)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the pattern, `yyyy-MM-dd HH.mm.ss.SSSSSS xxx`. Check the following sentence from the documentation of [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html):

> Pattern letter 'X' (upper case) will output 'Z' when the offset to be
> output would be zero, whereas pattern letter 'x' (lower case) will
> output '+00', '+0000', or '+00:00'.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        System.out.println(
                convertToDatabaseColumn(OffsetDateTime.of(LocalDateTime.of(2020, 7, 6, 6, 0, 0, 0), ZoneOffset.UTC)));
    }

    public static String convertToDatabaseColumn(OffsetDateTime offsetDateTime) {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH.mm.ss.SSSSSS xxx");
        return offsetDateTime.format(formatter);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-07-06 06.00.00.000000 +00:00
```

**Note:** You also have a typo, `-` between `dd` and `HH`, in your pattern.